Benjamini Hochberg Procedure
I am working on a problem for class related to multiple testing where I would like to run the BH procedure with a known $\pi_{0}$, denoting the proportion of hypothesis that are truly null, given simulated z-values from the bivariate normal distribution below:
set.seed(19)

#Computing 1,000 z-statistics according to the following scheme:

#Marginal distributions:
z1 <- rnorm(100, mean=3, sd=1)
z2 <- rnorm(length(101:1000), mean=0, sd=1)


#Create the correlation matrix
corr.matrix  <- matrix(0, nrow=1000, ncol=1000)

#if i,j > 100 the correlation=0.1
corr.matrix[101:1000, 101:1000] = 0.1

#Combining the distributions
Z <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu=c(rep(3,100), rep(0,900)), Sigma = as.matrix(corr.matrix))


#Using the Benjamini Procedure with known value .9, to reject as many hypothesis, 
# as possible subject to an FDR cutoff of 20%. 

However, the question doesn't indicate which p-value to use and I am wondering if I choose a two sided p-value how to retain the sign portion. Since in our class it was mentioned that two sided p-values retain the sign.

I was thinking of proceeding by obtaining the p-values. The following way:
2*pnorm(Z, lower.tail=FALSE) #To obtain the p-values. 

But, I am also confused as to how to implement the $\pi_{0}$, when proceeding to run the BH procedure. Are there any examples, here on how to implement this procedure or a similar one.
